# Using awk output to run mysqldump

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to learn more about shell scripts and have pieced this together if someone would please educate/critique the use of **awk** in particular. Because it's based on each value of the executed query, is this a viable option? Is there a better method, ie. for or while loop?

```
timestamp = $(date "+%Y=%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

user_dir = "server_dir_name"

backup_path = "/home1/$user_dir/public_html"

local_bckup_store = "/home1/$user_dir/backups"

db_prefix = "database_prefix"

db_user = "database_username"

db_pwd = "database_user_password" //used here for simplicity, not security

tar -zcvf "$local_bckup_store/$user_dir-public_html-$timestamp.tar.gz" $backup_path

mysql -NBr -u$db_user -p$db_pwd -Dinformation_schema -e "SELECT schema_name FROM schemata WHERE schema_name LIKE '/$db_prefix_%/"';"
| awk  '{ system("mysqldump -u$db_user -p$db_pwd $1 > $local_bckup_store/$1.$timestamp.sql | gzip" $1) }'
```

I will address the security issue of storing the *$db_pwd*, even though this will be stored and run locally on the server, but would appreciate some input on best practices.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for some actual effort on O.P.s part ;-) But what shell are you using that allows spaces around variable assignments (csh) AND `$( process substition )` (ksh|bash|zsh|others) ?  Good luck to all.

Comment: that was a mistake on my part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really just using awk to obtain the first parameter returned from your mysql statement.

I would recommend saving that param in a variable and then doing what you want with it.

UPDATED Example (I think this is what you want):

e.g.

```
while read schema_name ; do
  backup_file=${local_bckup_store}/${schema_name}.${timestamp}.sql
  mysqldump -u${db_user} -p${db_pwd} ${schema_name} > ${backup_file}
  gzip ${backup_file}
done < `mysql -NBr -u${db_user} -p${db_pwd} -Dinformation_schema -e "SELECT schema_name FROM schemata WHERE schema_name LIKE 'db_prefix_%';" | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Note the backticks, that runs the command and returns the STDOUT text, which will feed into the STDIN of the 'while read' line.  Also, I've put the shell variable names in parenthesis, this is also a good practice to help keep them from being incorrectly interpolated.

This way, you avoid awk having to exec another shell just to run the mysqldump command and your code is [slightly] easier to maintain.  As an added bonus, you can add error checking to be sure the mysql command succeeded before calling mysqldump.

Additionally, I would recommend using 'cut' instead of 'awk' for this, it's a bit more efficient for what you're trying to do.

FYI, you could also send the STDOUT of your mysqldump directly into the STDIN of gzip like such:

```
mysqldump -u${db_user} -p${db_pwd} ${schema_name} | gzip > ${backup_file}.gz
```

Comment: A little confused...

I started with **awk '{print $1}'** so I could see if my logic was right, and it was: it printed out schema_name\n for all the db names in information_schema. I assumed, then, that the mysqldump needed to be within the awk '{}' so as it read each row it would process.

New question would be: since **gzip_filename = `...`** returns STDOUT based on the awk '{print $1}', would it do the **mysqldump** and return to the next **$1**?

Comment: No, you would need to loop through the schemas returned by mysql.  I'll update the example with a loop.

Comment: I don't have mysql here, so I couldn't test my code so keep in mind the example is pseudocode, but _should_ work, or at least be close enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't a 'stupid' question, but from some of the other posts I've read, does the result of the mysql return much like it would if I were doing this in php – meaning **awk** really isn't needed or am I not understanding?

Comment: There are no 'stupid' questions.  =)  No, I really don't think awk is the tool you need for what you're trying to accomplish.  Awk was created to be a line parser before other, more efficient tools came into being (such as Perl).  So, yeah, you can pretty much use the output of mysql similar to the way you would in other programming languages (like PHP).

Comment: Thanks @Donovan! I really appreciate the education and love when things finally click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea, but you really arent doing enough text parsing you warrant `awk`, you can do it all in bash like this.

```
query = "SELECT schema_name FROM schemata WHERE schema_name LIKE 'db_prefix_%';"
mysql -NBr -u$db_user -p$db_pwd -Dinformation_schema -e $query | while read line
do
    arr=($line)
    mysqldump -u$db_user -p$db_pwd ${arr[0]} > $local_bckup_store/${arr[0]}.$timestamp.sql && gzip $local_bckup_store/${arr[0]}.$timestamp.sql
done
```

`bash` will create an array by splitting the string on whitespace for you (this is the point of `arr=($line)`).

Comment: Wouldn't you need:
    ${arr[0]} **>** $local_bckup_store/${arr[0]}.$timestamp.sql | gzip ${arr[0]}

Answer (score 0):

This awk command is problematic:

```
awk '{ system("mysqldump -u$db_user -p$db_pwd $1 > $local_bckup_store/$1.$timestamp.sql | gzip" $1) }'
```

Since awk cannot use shell variables `$db_user` etc like that in single quoted. To pass shell variables to awk use this syntax:

```
awk -v $db_user="$db_user" -vdb_pwd="$db_pwd" ts="$timestamp" '{ 
system("mysqldump -udb_user -pdb_pwd " $1 " > $local_bckup_store/" $1 "." ts ".sql | gzip" $1) }'
```

PS: You `mysqldump | awk` is stil untested here.

Another option is to do it directly in shell as:

```
schema=$(mysql -NBr -u$db_user -p$db_pwd -Dinformation_schema -e "SELECT schema_name FROM schemata WHERE schema_name LIKE 'db_prefix_%';")

mysqldump -u$db_user -p$db_pwd "$schema" > "$local_bckup_store/$schema.$timestamp.sql"
```